# Unable to infer generic type when also used as type param in another generic class

Tags: java, generics

Consider the code below. Why do I have to cast to String in the withCastTest and not in the withoutCastTest?

It seems like java is unable to infer the generic class when the type parameter is used as a type parameter in another generic class. In the withoutCastTest I send the type parameter as a normal parameter and it can infer the correct type. Why is that? Anyway around it?

Sry if the question is formulated weird, I'm not sure about the naming conventions.

```
public class RandomHelper {

    public interface RandomInterface<E> {
        public abstract E get();
    }

    public static abstract class Randomable<E> implements RandomInterface {

        protected E object;

        public Randomable(E object) {
            this.object = object;
        }

    }

    public static <E> E withCastTest(RandomInterface<E> action) {
        E savedObject = action.get();
        return savedObject;
    }

    public static <E> E withoutCastTest(RandomInterface<E> action, E e) {
        E savedObject = action.get();
        return savedObject;
    }

}

public class TestJava {

    public void run() {
        String s ="test";
        String ret = (String) RandomHelper.withCastTest(new Randomable<String>(s) {

            @Override
            public String get() {
                return object;
            }
        });

        String ret2 = RandomHelper.withoutCastTest(new Randomable<String>(s) {

            @Override
            public String get() {
                return object;
            }
        }, "test2");

        System.out.println(ret);
        System.out.println(ret2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestJava test = new TestJava();
        test.run();
    }

}
```

Edit: Typo in code

Comment: You are using generics for your interface `RandomInterface<E>` but just implement it as a rawtype when implementing it to `Randomable<E>` by not providing `RandomInterface<E>`. You are also just calling `withoutCastTest` and `withCastTest` as a rawtype, but `withoutCastTest` gets his information about the ruturntype because it gets provided by the parameter `e`. Edit: also almost the whole run method gives you an `unchecked` warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the parameter `<E>` after `implements RandomInterface` in

```
public abstract class Randomable<E> implements RandomInterface<E> {
```

Then you need to change : (note the return type of `get` methods)

```
    String ret = RandomHelper.withCastTest(new Randomable<String>(s) {

        @Override
        public String get() {
            return s;
        }
    });

    String ret2 = RandomHelper.withoutCastTest(new Randomable<String>(s) {
        @Override
        public String get() {
            return s;
        }
    }, "test2");
```

Comment: Ah that was the problem, thanks alot! Yeah, I realized the get problems. Typos when creating the test case.

Answer (score 1):

your abstract class does not implement the generic interface

```
Randomable<E> implements RandomInterface<E>
```

is missing.

Also your implementations can not return Object, but must return String as type